# iPhone timer task for long processes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, timer

When the application enters into background state, the time used to run in background is not working. Following is the code.

In AppDelegate.h,

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    BOOL status;
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
}
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSAssert(self->bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
            self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([application backgroundTimeRemaining] > 1.0) {
            // Start background service synchronously
            [[vController getInstance] run];

        }

        [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
        self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    });
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    NSAssert(self->bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
            self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([application backgroundTimeRemaining] > 1.0) {

            // Start background service synchronously
            [[vController getInstance] stopbackground];

        }

        [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
        self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    });
}
```

And in view Controller.h,

```
@interface vController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
-(void) run;
-(void) stopbackground;
-(void) getMessage:(NSTimer*)theTimer;;
+(vController*) getInstance;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer * timer;
@end
```

the view controller.m,

```
@implementation vController
@synthesize timer;
vController *tvc;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tvc = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

+ (vController*) getInstance
{
    return tvc;
}

- (void)stopbackground
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(getMessage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)run
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(getMessage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) getMessage:(NSTimer*) theTimer
{

    NSError *error;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (theAudio == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Hi");
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void) dealloc{
    [timer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am using it on simulator 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, this may not be possible. Namely, Apple does not let you execute code in the 'background' unless you are performing one of the following tasks:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Read more at :http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... I need to download something via http communication, and process the data received at regulare interval of time??

Comment: That is an implementation detail (the downloading via http).  Which of the above bullet points is your app doing?  Well it can't be "regular updates from external accessores", can't be "VoIP", can't be "navigation app", I would bet that it isn't "music player app".  That leaves "newsstand apps"... If you are not making a "newsstand app" or my assumptions are wrong, you should not try to run code in the background if you want your app to be approved for the AppStore.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.... this is the basic requirement of the app that it should go to some server and fetch the data via http at regular interval of time..

Answer (score 0):

By Creating Instance you can Run Background Task in Any View-controller like Below:

// Declare the following in `YourViewController.h` file.

```
+ (YourViewController *)getInstance;
- (void)run;
-(void)stopbackground;
```

// Define the Vollowing in YourViewController.m file.

```
static  YourViewController *instance = NULL;

+(YourViewController *)getInstance {

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == NULL) {
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}


- (void)run

{
// strat Back ground task
}
-(void)stopbackground
{
// Stop Background task
}
```

in `AppDelegate.h` file Declare the Following

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
```

in `AppDelegate.m` file use the Following Methods.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Application entered background state.");

    // bgTask is instance variable
    NSAssert(self->bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
            self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([application backgroundTimeRemaining] > 1.0) {
            // Start background service synchronously
[[YourViewController getInstance] run];

        }

        [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
        self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    });
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"Application entered background state.");

    // bgTask is instance variable
    NSAssert(self->bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
            self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([application backgroundTimeRemaining] > 1.0) {

 // Start background service synchronously
  [[YourViewController getInstance] stopbackground];

        }

        [application endBackgroundTask:self->bgTask];
        self->bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    });


    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Comment: thax a lot for your reply.. Siba Prasad, i will try it.. thanx

Comment: Do i need to use Timer in the Run and StopBackground methods to run the task repeated on regular interval of time?? Pls help...

Comment: Yes You can use Timer with Repeat YES/NO

Comment: Hi Siba Prasad, I have used the code, and facing a problem that the Timer used in run method [When applicatio goes in background] is not firing its Target Method in which i am trying to play a sound for alerts. While the same method is called from the Timer of stopBackground method, and its working .... Pls help

Comment: Can you Post all Your Codes, And Edit your Question Again ? it will be helpful for us to find the issue.

Comment: I havn't tested it yet on iPhone device.. I am using only iphone simulator, could it be a reason for the non working of the code. Please help...

Comment: i don't think Simulator would be a Problem, Even its Working perfectly for me in simulator also. I m trying my best to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using it on Simulator version 6.0. On which version are you getting perfect execution?

Comment: You can downloaded the Code from here : http://www.cogzentappz.com/demo/iostutorial/BackgroundtaskChecker.zip   and test. Hope it will work for you. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanx a lot but the Problem still not solved... My code is also working in the same manner. But when the Timers are intorduced its not working.. the timers that are used in Run and StopBackground methods are getting initialized but their target method is not invoking, so i can not perform the task periodically in background or sleep mode. Moreover i introduced timers in the code given by you, but the result is same... Not invoking...